# Modular Exponentiation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Give numbers $x,y,z$ such that $y \equiv z \pmod{5}$ but $x^y \not\equiv x^z \pmod{5}$

I'm just learning modular arithmetic and this questions has me puzzled. Any help with explanation would be great!

Comment: In general, $x^y \equiv x^z \mod 5$ if $z - y$ is divisible by the order of the element $x$ in the cyclic group $\Bbb Z_5^*$. For generators $x$ of $\Bbb Z_5^*$ ($x = 2, 3$), this order is $\phi(5) = 4$. So for instance, $2^y \equiv 2^{y+4} \equiv 2^{y+8} \equiv \ldots \not\equiv 2^{y+5}$, which leads to lhf's choice of $x = 2$ and $z = y + 5$.

Answer (score 2):

Pick $x = 2$, because it's small and not zero or one. Then $y = 0$ because that's easy to deal with. Try $z = 5$. Is $2^5 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$?

It turns out that exponents are not equivalent mod 5, but by 4. $x^k \equiv x^{k + 4n} \pmod{5}$ for all $n$. This is because of one of Euler's (many) theorems: for all $n$ and $x$, $x^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=2$, $y=3$, $z=8$. Then $x^y \bmod 5 = 3$ but $x^z \bmod 5 = 1$.